# Storing items of with different generic type parameters in collection

Tags: c#, generics, generic-collections

I realise there are several posts on here regarding my question, but none seem to offer a solution particular to my case.

I have a short static class, looking like this:

```
public static class NotificationCenter
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> Notifiers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static INotifier<T> NotifierForType<T>()
    {
        object notifier = null;
        return Notifiers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out notifier) 
            ? (INotifier<T>)notifier 
            : null;
    }

    public static void RegisterNotifier<T>(INotifier<T> notifier)
    {
        Notifiers[typeof(T)] = notifier;
    }
}
```

The above works fine, but I'm not keen on storing the `INotifiers` in an `IDictionary<Type, object>` - specifically, I'm not keen on the `object` part, because it makes the collection non-type-safe.

I've read many similar posts that recommend deriving `INotifier<T>` from a base interface called `INotifier`, but I don't believe this is suitable in my instance, because the `INotifier<T>` interface looks like this:

```
interface INotifier<T>
{
    void Notify(T notification);
}
```

If I were to derive from a base class, the base class would not be able to implement the Notify method (unless it were implemented with the signature `void Notify(object notification)` but then we're back to square one), and that is what I want the client of the `INotifier<T>` class to be able to invoke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to enumerate all notifiers? If not the solution can be pretty simple:

```
namespace NotifierTest
{
    interface INotifier<T>
    {
        void Notify(T notification);
    }

    class Notifier<T> : INotifier<T>
    {
        public void Notify(T notification) 
        {
            Debug.Print("Notify: " + notification);
        }
    }

    static class NotificationCenter<T>
    {
        public static INotifier<T> notifier;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            NotificationCenter<int>.notifier = new Notifier<int>();
            NotificationCenter<int>.notifier.Notify(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple enough solution.  I think I'm going to change it so that I don't have singleton instances though, and so clients have access to concrete classes that implement INotifier for various generic type arguments, and can instantiate them.  A NotificationCenter seems overkill - I wanted to create a service class that holds references to all notifiers, but I've now decided it's not required.